# Large PnP driver buffer

Tags: c, windows, memory, kernel, buffer

I'm developing a kernel PnP driver to map my FPGA. I need four 32Mb buffer of contiguous memory as I use a non scatter gather DMA. Right now I have a problem allocating them with WdfCommonBufferCreate as sometime it works, sometimes don't. I don't understand why the allocation fails sporadically as the device memory and devices does not changes.

Is there a way to ensure my buffer will be created? What can cause the sporadic fail?

I also thought removing 128Mb from Windows with Bcdedit and use the space left for my buffer.  I have no problem doing that since the driver is for a specific platform in a controlled environnement but I did not found a way to know memory size with Windows Driver API.

Is there a way to know the size of actual memory? Can I actually use the memory left and if yes, how?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of contiguous memory.  The Windows Driver Framework can break up large DMA transactions into a size your driver can handle, if you tell it the maximum amount of scatter/gather descriptors you have through `WdfDmaEnablerSetMaximumScatterGatherElements`.  Just use a smaller fixed number of scatter/gather elements.